# Android AdMob Mediation - not receiving mediated networks ads

Tags: android, admob, flurry

I am trying to set up my Android app to show ads from the mediated networks (which by the way, has no good explanation anywhere), and here is what I have done so far:

1) I have copied the publisher ID to the xml view which will show the ads, and now, only AdMob ads show correctly on the device

2) I have created ad spaces in the associated networks, and connected them to my AdMob mediation, using the IDs provided by the networks.

3) I have imported the needed SDKs and adapters for the networks in my project

4) I have added the needed permissions and activities of the networks in my Manifest

Now this is my code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    FlurryAdapterExtras flurryAdapterExtras = new FlurryAdapterExtras();
    flurryAdapterExtras.setLogEnabled(true);
    FlurryAgent.setLogLevel(Log.VERBOSE);

    MillennialAdapterExtras millenialAdapterExtras = new MillennialAdapterExtras();

    AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
        .addTestDevice("600447FDC2D619692F94F848E532BAC3")
        .addNetworkExtras(flurryAdapterExtras)
        .addNetworkExtras(millenialAdapterExtras)
        .build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

}
```

And I am receiving only ads from AdMob, there is not even a mention of the other networks in the LogCat...

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will only receive an ad from another network

1. If they have an ad for you at this point in time
2. They are placed higher in the mediation flow than Admob
3. You aren't asking for test ads

Comment: so is my code correct? is that all I need to have in the app in order for the user to get ads from admob and the mediated networks?

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong. 
This means TEST DEVICE so are receiving only test ads.

```
 .addTestDevice("600447FDC2D619692F94F848E532BAC3")
```

You can remove that line to receive real ads. Be cautious because clicking on your own ads is a huge no no. Also, since your in test mode there will be no other network ads.

Comment: so if I remove this I will start getting other networks ads? what about AdMob, wont they ban me if I show myself real ads (but not clicking them)

Comment: No, you don't get banned for looking at your own real ads. You can get banned for clicking on the ads. If everything else is working correctly yes you should eventually see other network ads.

Comment: well I don't know if everything else is working correctly, I am still receiving ads only from AdMob :/